# Ябеда и ябедник

Tags: употребление-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, слово "ябеда" — это, скажем так, сам донос или человек, который его делает? Или человек все-таки называется "ябедник"?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И то, и другое:http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/28/str368.html

С точки зрения этимологии  слово интересное. Оно - переработанное до
неузнаваемости русским языком - представляет собою как бы окаменелость
старого скандинавского "embaetti", значившего "служба", "контора". Немцы из
этого древнего северного германизма сделали свой "Ammt" - "контора", а
русский язык превратил то же "embaetti" в старинное "ябедник" - "служащий",
"чиновник"; в старых бумагах мы его с этим значением и находим. Несколько
позже с ним связался другой смысл - "доносчик", а отсюда уже отделилось слово
"ябеда" в смысле "действия ябедника", "сам донос".

Ябеда как доносчик- разговорное от ябедник - воспринимается как сущ. общего рода, обознач. лицо, как донос - устаревшее значение, но оно есть. У слова "ябедник" тоже осталось устаревшее знач."чел., кот .занимается сутяжничеством, крючкотворством".

Comment: Ябедник  и  древнерусских  текстах  проходит  по  сыскной  или  судебной  линии,  в  18-м  веке  закрепляется  как  сутяга,  а  там  и  до  доносчика   недалеко.  Сейчас  это  фигура  детской  речи  в  том  же  значении.